# Проблема с миграциями в базу на PostgreSQL

Tags: .net, postgresql, asp.net-core, .net-core

Я не могу понять где я что-то сделал ни так. Я добавляю 1 миграцию, она создаётся корректно. Конекшн стринг и тд настройки все выставлены корректно для конекшна к базе. Я создал верный контекст. Миграция созддана черех пакет менеджер консоль, следуюющим делом я делаю в той же консоли update-database. И вуоля ошибка...

```
    Exception data:
    Severity: ERROR
    SqlState: 42601
    MessageText: syntax error at or near ")"
    Position: 88
    File: scan.l
    Line: 1149
    Routine: scanner_yyerror
42601: syntax error at or near ")"

Failed executing DbCommand (8ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
CREATE TABLE "Projects" (
    "Id" integer NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (),
    "Name" character varying(200) NOT NULL,
    "EngagementTypeId" integer NULL,
    "Description" text NULL,
    "CreatedAt" timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    "EditedAt" timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "PK_Projects" PRIMARY KEY ("Id"),
    CONSTRAINT "FK_Projects_EngagementTypes_EngagementTypeId" FOREIGN KEY ("EngagementTypeId") REFERENCES "EngagementTypes" ("Id") ON DELETE RESTRICT
);
```

Comment: Вставляйте ошибки и *SQL* текстом, а не скринами!

Comment: @Ainar-G, прошу простить. Уже горит одно место несусветно. Целый день пытаюсь пофиксить

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в скобках после `AS IDENTITY`.  Там должны быть
опции последовательности.  Если их нету, то и скобок быть не должно:

```sql
    "Id" integer NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
```

Comment: А почему это возникает. Если я всего-лишь прописал создать миграцию. Я этим кодом никак не управляю

Comment: Это уже вопрос к вам (как именно создавали миграции?) и разработчикам ваших инструментов для миграции (почему они допускают создание миграций с неверным синтаксисом?).

Comment: так проблема в чём заключается. и как это фиксить

Comment: Я не знаю.  Я указал на конкретную ошибку в генерируемом *SQL.*  Дальше вам нужен кто-то, кто разбирается в вашем фреймворке.  А чтобы они ваш вопрос заметили, добавьте фреймворк в метки вопроса.